# ActiveX is alway on Top

Tags: c#, visual-c++, matlab, activex, ocx

In LabWindows CVI from National Instruments, I added a gauge from [BeauGauge Control](http://www.beaugauge.com), it is an typical ActiveX Control. Whatever I did, the gauge I created was always put on the top most than other system controls. Is there a way to solve it? Thanks in advance.

[image: Gauge from BeauGauge Control]

Comment: Not sure why this has a MATLAB tag?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the fact that the ActiveX control is not really a part of the UI panel but it behaves more like a floating child window that is always on top. Thus changing the order of your UI controls doesn't affect the ActiveX control.